# Converting A NSDate Array to a String Array in Swift

Tags: string, swift, parse-platform, nsdateformatter

I am a bit new to swift and IOS coding. I have a NSdate array which is retrieved from parse "CreatedAt" column. I need to convert that array to a string array so I can use it as an input for a text label in tableview cells.

```
//I try the below, I defined resultsDateArrayString as string array variable, and resultsDateArray as NSdate array variable.

      var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        resultsDateArrayString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self.resultsDateArray)

        cell.postDateTxt.text = self.resultsDateArrayString[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: You  tagged your question with [nsdateformatter] so you already seem know how to convert a date to a string ...

Comment: Actually i tried it but could not make it happen with an array.

Comment: What did you try? – `self.resultsDateArray` is an *array*. `self.resultsDateArray[indexPath.row]` is an element of that array, i.e. a *date* ... Now take that date and convert is to a *string*.

Comment: I updated what I am trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a highly inefficient way of formatting the dates into a `String` since it instantiates a new `NSDateFormatter` each time. Consider creating a constant `NSDateFormatter` for the class as an optimisation.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
    formatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
    formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    cell.textLabel!.text = formatter.stringFromDate(resultsDateArray[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

To get that `hh:mm` format that you've mentioned in your updated question, then simply delete the line `formatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle`

Comment: Hello Kumuluzz, thank you very much for the answer. I updated as your codes, however when I run I get an error   "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in the part:                  self.resultsDateArray.append(object.objectForKey("createdAt") as! NSDate)
why might this happen?

Comment: Most likely because there isn't a "createdAt" property for that specific object. I would recommend safely unwrapping the result from `objectForKey`. Something similar to:
    `if let date = object.objectForKey("createdAt") as! NSDate { self.resultsDateArray.append(date) }`

Comment: Another alternative is because you haven't initialized your `resultsDateArray`. You can initialize it like so:
`var resultsDateArray: [NSDate] = []`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487622/unable-to-retrieve-createdat-values-from-parse-objects    in this link there is a similar problem saying use object.updatedAt rather than objectforkey("updatedAt") but it doesnt work also. I have initialized the array by the way.

Comment: How are you generating the data? By querying the Parse backend? Or creating them locally? Because if you create them locally, then their `createdAt` property is nil. You have to have saved it in the backend, which automatically sets this value

Comment: I have a tweets class in parse whenever a customer enters a tweet the createdat column is automatically filled. The other columns in the class are retrieved fine, when i commentout the createdat appending line everyting works fine actually.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a map function with NSDateFormatter wrapped around each date with the output format you want.

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = ...
var strings = dates.map{dateFormatter.stringFromDate($0)}
```